# Trying to write object to internal storage causes NotSerializableException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a object to internal storage.

This causes: "java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"

```
public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object)
        throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}

public class Squarevaluse implements Serializable{
    String repoName;
    String repoDescrption;
    String repoOwnerName;
    String repoFork;
    String repoUrl;
    String OwnerUrl;
    Context context;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `Squarevalue` class static, and remove the `context` field:

```
public static class SquareValue implements Serializable {
    String repoName;
    String repoDescrption;
    String repoOwnerName;
    String repoFork; 
    String repoUrl;
    String OwnerUrl;
}
```

If the class isn't static, the parent class also needs to implement Serializable. Since this is a data class, it can easily be made static.

Context isn't Serializable, though, so you can't use it in a Serializable class. You'll need to find some other way of passing a Context object to where you need it (in a RecyclerView Adapter it isn't so hard: just create a custom constructor that takes a Context object and assigns it to a global variable; if you have access to a View object, use `view.getContext()`).

---

I also renamed your class to conform to Java syntax guidelines. Classes are `TitleCase`, so every "word" gets its first letter capitalized.